# Mount TrueCrypt volume with NTFS on Linux command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ntfs, truecrypt

I have a hard disk containing a TrueCrypt volume on /dev/sdc. It is formated with NTFS. I am running Ubuntu 9.4.

To mount the volume I tried this:

```
 sudo truecrypt -t -k "" --protect-hidden=no /dev/sdc /mnt/data
```

After providing the correct password I get the following error:

```
Error: $LogFile indicates unclean shutdown (0, 0)
Failed to mount '/dev/mapper/truecrypt1': Operation not supported
Mount is denied because NTFS is marked to be in use. Choose one action:

Choice 1: If you have Windows then disconnect the external devices by
          clicking on the 'Safely Remove Hardware' icon in the Windows
          taskbar then shutdown Windows cleanly.

Choice 2: If you don't have Windows then you can use the 'force' option for
          your own responsibility. For example type on the command line:

            mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/mapper/truecrypt1 /mnt/data -o force

    Or add the option to the relevant row in the /etc/fstab file:

            /dev/mapper/truecrypt1 /mnt/data ntfs-3g force 0 0
```

I think, I need to pass the force mount-option somehow to the mount command. But how? The following does not work:

```
sudo truecrypt -t -k "" --protect-hidden=no --mount-options="-o force" /dev/sdc /mnt/data
Error: Unknown option: -o force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **--fs-options=force**

```
sudo truecrypt -t -k "" --protect-hidden=no --fs-options=force /dev/sdc /mnt/data
```